# Hosting multiple websites on same server (IIS 7.5, Windows 2008)

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have created 3 web sites on IIS 7.5, Windows 2008 server

- DefaultWebSite
- www.site1.com
- www.site2.com

updated the bindings with IP address and domain names for site1 and site2 accordingly,
but when I browse (external browser) www.site1.com and www.site2.com both redirects to DefaultWebSite.

Is there anything other than I've done to make this work properly?

Comment: It worked when I changed binding to HostName:www.<site>.com, port:80, IpAddress:*

Answer (score 0):

Solution from [Nalaka526](https://serverfault.com/users/97146/nalaka526)'s comment

It worked when I changed binding to `HostName:www.<site>.com, port:80, IpAddress:*`